# GraphFrame: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, graphframes

I am trying to create a graph using spark graphframe

here is the code:

```
import org.graphframes._

// Node DataFrames
val v = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
  ("d", "David", 29),
  ("e", "Esther", 32),
  ("f", "Fanny", 36),
  ("g", "Gabby", 60)
)).toDF("id", "name", "age")

// Edge DataFrame
val e = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "c", "follow"),
  ("c", "b", "follow"),
  ("f", "c", "follow"),
  ("e", "f", "follow"),
  ("e", "d", "friend"),
  ("d", "a", "friend"),
  ("a", "e", "friend")
)).toDF("src", "dst", "relationship")

// Create a GraphFrame
val g = GraphFrame(v, e)
```

But this is the error I am getting:

> error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file
>   'GraphFrame.class'. Could not access type Logging in package
>   org.apache.spark, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check
>   your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run
>   with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full
>   rebuild may help if 'GraphFrame.class' was compiled against an
>   incompatible version of org.apache.spark.

I am using Apache Spark 2.1 and Scala 2.11. Any suggestion what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Download following packages from maven central repo

```
com.typesafe.scala-logging_scala-logging-api_2.11-2.1.2.jar    
graphframes_graphframes-0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11.jar  
org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
com.typesafe.scala-logging_scala-logging-slf4j_2.11-2.1.2.jar  
org.scala-lang_scala-reflect-2.11.0.jar
```

Add the following to your sparks-default.conf file(comma separated list of absolute path where the above downloaded jars are located)

```
spark.jars            path_2_jar/org.slf4j_slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, path_2_jar/org.scala-lang_scala-reflect-2.11.0.jar, path_2_jar/graphframes_graphframes-0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11.jar, path_2_jar/com.typesafe.scala-logging_scala-logging-slf4j_2.11-2.1.2.jar, path_2_jar/com.typesafe.scala-logging_scala-logging-api_2.11-2.1.2.jar
```